# IN operator in SQL Statement Does not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table MyTable, with the following 3 columns, P(bigint), F(bigint), D(bigint).

Now what I need to do is to group all records by same P value, then in each group, calculate the following value:

```
V = ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)
```

for each record, and delete all records in the group, except for the one with the minimum value of V.

So I write the SQL statement as follows:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE (P, ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) NOT IN (SELECT P, MIN(ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) FROM MyTable GROUP BY P HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

But in SQL Server, I will get the following error:

```
Msg 4145 SQL Server An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,near ','
```

Why? Also whether bitwise and & works in SQL Server 2005? I only have SQL Server 2008 R2 and the online document at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 does not indicate whether it support 2005 & 2008.

**Update1**

P, F, D are all bigint type.

**Update2**

With the helps of others, I finally write a query with NOT EXISTS, as follows:

Method 1: DELETE t FROM MyTable t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT P, MIN(ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) as minpf
  FROM MyTable GROUP BY P) tt WHERE tt.P = t.P AND tt.minpf = ABS((t.P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - t.F))

**Note: I remove the HAVE COUNT(*) > 1, otherwise, the statement will also delete those records who are in a group with only one record.**

Though it works, I doubt its performance. Since in most of the groups(group by P), there will only be one record, while calculating the minpf in such a group and then delete the record with the calculated value <> minpf is wasting time(no records are deleted in such a group). So just wonder if there are better way to do the same thing?

**Update 3**

I test the performance of my method(method 1) with the two methods Gordon provided(with minor revision)

Method 2:

DELETE t
    FROM MyTable t LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT P, MIN(ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) as minpf
          FROM MyTable
          GROUP BY P
         ) tt
         ON tt.p = t.p AND tt.minpf = (tt.P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - tt.F)
    WHERE tt.P IS NULL;

Method 3:

DELETE t FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) as seqnum
          FROM MyTable t
         ) t
     WHERE seqnum > 1;

The performance data are below:

First Test:

(22721 rows affected)
Method 1:16094

(22721 rows affected)
Method 2:17156

(22721 rows affected)
Method 3:12188

Second Test:

(22721 rows affected)
Method 1:26297

(22721 rows affected)
Method 2:27562

(22721 rows affected)
Method 3:11625

3rd Test:

(22721 rows affected)
Method 1:26297

(22721 rows affected)
Method 2:27359

(22721 rows affected)
Method 3:11578

So based on the test, method 3 has the best performance.

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: Agree with @jarlh on `NOT EXISTS`. `NOT IN` has "unexpected" (it's expected if you know it does it) behaviour with `NULL` values. For example. `SELECT 1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT N FROM (VALUES(2),(3),(NULL))V(N));` will return no values, despite that `1` is not in the subquery.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you very much. I just rewrite the query with NOT EXISTS, its complex and I doubt its performance is not good enough. Do you have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, simply use a `JOIN`:

```
DELETE t
    FROM MyTable t LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT P, MIN(ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) as minpf
          FROM MyTable
          GROUP BY P
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
         ) tt
         ON tt.p = t.p AND tt.minpf = (tt.P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - tt.F)
    WHERE tt.P IS NULL;
```

Or, more simply use window functions:

```
DELETE t
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER(*) OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F) as seqnum
          FROM MyTable t
         ) t
     WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the first query will delete the records if there are only one record in the group(group by P), which is not desired. The second query seems to miss a right ).

Comment: Remove "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" will solve the problem but may decrease the performance a lot?

Comment: @alancc . . . The second query should have `ROW_NUMBER()` if you want to keep one row per group.  Your pseudo code uses `COUNT(*)` suggesting that you want to delete all groups with more than 1 member, but I see that the text is clearer on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much. For all groups with more than one member, I will keep the member with the minimum value, and delete all the remainings.

Comment: Also the HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 in my first query is incorrect since NOT IN will cause it excludes those group with only one member.

Comment: What is the usage of the last t in your 2nd query? I try to remove it, but SQL Server reports error.

Comment: Also what is the usage of the first t in 2nd query. I try to remove it, but SQL Server also reports error.

Comment: These are table aliases, which SQL Server -- and many other databases -- require.

Comment: Thank you. But the last t is used to name the inner SELECT query, while the first t is the alias of MyTable. Will these two conflict with each other?

Comment: @alancc . . . Not at all.  One is in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

IN statements do work, but they do not work in the way you use them - simple like that. The content of IN is a list of compare values, not another sql statement.

In your case you do not IN - you do delete form select with join and use that to define the rows to delete.

Comment: "*The content of IN is a list of compare values, not another sql statement.*" that's wrong. `where id in (select x from ..)` is perfectly valid. In standard SQL the query from the question would also be valid (`where (a,b) in (select x,y ..)`, however SQL Server does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

the `select` query after `IN` must return only one column , test it first

Comment: In the SQL standard a multi-column IN like `where (a,b) in (select x,y ..)` is allowed - but SQL Server does not support in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DELETE FROM MyTable 
WHERE concat(P, ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) NOT IN (SELECT concat( P, MIN(ABS((P & 
0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F))) FROM MyTable GROUP BY P HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Sorry but it seems the contact function is not available in SQL Server 2008 R2