# Delete from a derived table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, derived-table

I am studying the query in the answer of the post [IN operator in SQL Statement Does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317803/in-operator-in-sql-statement-does-not-work/60319476?noredirect=1#comment106755854_60319476), as below:

```
DELETE t
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER(*) OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F) as seqnum
          FROM MyTable t
         ) t
     WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

After many researchs, I finally figure out most of the issues, and revised the query as below:

```
DELETE t2
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) as seqnum
          FROM MyTable t
         ) t2
     WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

The changes are:

1. Add ")" after "F)", so that "OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F))" follow the syntax at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
2. Change ROW_NUMBER(*) to ROW_NUMBER() since the document above use ROW_NUBMER().
3. Change the t in the outer query to t2. The subquery in FROM clause must have an alias, so there must be an alias after the subquery. See [(T-SQL) Why does this subquery need an alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616939/t-sql-why-does-this-subquery-need-an-alias) . Moreover, actual the alias in the outer query can be same as the one in the subquery, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/subqueries-aliases-same-as-main-queries-aliases, but they are refer to different objects. So I change the alias in the outer query from "t" to "t2"

It is a bit difficult for a novice to understand many knowledges in a complex query. Whatmore, I still have two things that cannot understand very well.

1. Why I must write "Delete t2 FROM" instead of "Delete FROM"? I only find this link [Difference between DELETE and DELETE FROM in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336807/difference-between-delete-and-delete-from-in-sql) , but it is used for JOIN table, not for subquery.
2. From the link at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120233/sql-server-delete-from-subquery-derived-table, I know the subquery is a derived table. Then the DELETE from t2 is just delete records from a dervied table(it is virtual), why it can also perform the same deletion operation on the underlying real table MyTable?

Thanks

Comment: Your primary source of confusion is the syntax of `DELETE`. You can write `DELETE FROM t2 FROM <some subquery>`. You can write the keyword `FROM` twice. The first `FROM` is optional. It much more readable to wrap subquery in CTE, as @Lukasz showed in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why I must write "Delete t2 FROM" instead of "Delete FROM"?

It is because of the [DELETE syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql)

```
DELETE   
    [ FROM ]   <--optional keyword FROM
    { { table_alias  
      | <object>   <--> <object> ::= table_or_view_name
      | @table_variable 
    }
    [ FROM table_source [ ,...n ] ]  <-- note the whole FROM statement is optional, not only the FROM keyword
......

FROM table_source
Specifies an additional FROM clause. **This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE** allows specifying data from <table_source> and deleting the corresponding rows from the table in the first FROM clause.
```

DELETE (optional FROM) and could use either 
   a table alias
   or an object which is a table or a view

There is no derived table/table_source after the DELETE, so (for deleting from a derived table) the only applicable option is to use an alias.
The second FROM accepts a table_source, which could be a derived table.
Hence, in a case of a derived table

```
DELETE [FROM] alias
FROM (....) as alias
```

> why it can also perform the same deletion operation on the underlying
>   real table MyTable

As long as the derived table keeps the granularity of each row (each row can be identified individually) and the scope of the dml is limited to a single table (taking into account the derived table definition) then dml operations on derived tables, views, ctes are possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is the best one!

Answer (score 3):

> *"Why I must write "Delete t2 FROM" instead of "Delete FROM"?*

The easiest way is first to write a query that makes selection and then delete from it, for instance by using CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM (
     SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P ORDER BY ABS((P & 0xFFFFFFFF) * 256 - F)) as seqnum
     FROM MyTable t) sub
   WHERE seqnum > 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte; -- selecting
--DELETE FROM cte; -- deletion, no where condition, only the ones selected will be removed
```

---

> *Then the DELETE from t2 is just delete records from a dervied table(it is virtual), why it can also perform the same deletion operation on the underlying real table MyTable?*

It is similar case to deleting from view. Rows can be deleted from derived table as long as SQL operations preserve key(no aggregations, DISTINCT, n:m relationship).

In this scenario adding window function introduces one new column, but it is always 1:1 to the existing data.